# Where is NUNIT result xml in nunit-vs-adapter

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nunit

I am using nunit with VS 2015 and nunit-vs-adapter and want to process the test results. I founf that the console runner creates a sort of result xml and I want to know where I can find it when running the tests inside VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter doesn't save the test results as a file. You could, of course, make a request for such a feature from the project at https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter. It would require a new setting in the runsettings file.